# Mirror Files and Documents from Windows machine to Ubuntu in Virtualbox

Tags: 12.10, windows, virtualbox, shared-folders, symbolic-link

Ok, so I have a machine with a dual boot installed (Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10). They are on separate hard drives. I already have Virtualbox set up to boot from the linux physical hard drive (Windows 8 Host). I also have shared my Windows User folder using the Virtualbox folder share. Here is my problem: I would love to be able to just go to the Documents folder to access my Windows folder Documents. I think there is a way to do this with symlinks... but sometimes I do need to boot just into Ubuntu (not in Virtualbox) and it messes up the symlinks (because the Windows Documents are now not accessible via the Virtualbox folder but through the actual hard drive). Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks all who were trying to help.

I finally figured it out.

Here is what I did:

```
sudo gedit /usr/local/bin/mountscript.sh
```

In Virtualbox make sure to create a share for what ever drive you want to access (mine is C), and name the share C. Oh, and make sure it is marked permanent.

Paste in this and save (make sure and replace [UBUNTU_USERNAME] and [WINDOWS_USERNAME] with their respective usernames):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -t vboxsf C /media/C
sudo mount --bind /media/C/Users/[WINDOWS_USERNAME]/Documents/ ~/Documents/
sudo mount --bind /media/[UBUNTU_USERNAME]/C/Users/[WINDOWS_USERNAME]/Documents /home/[UBUNTU_USERNAME]/Documents
```

Then to make it executable run this:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mountscript.sh
```

Then to make sure you do not have to enter your password each time you boot:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then at the end add this:

```
[UBUNTU_USERNAME] ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/mountscript.sh, /bin/mount
```

Then open the dash and search for: Startup Applications.

Click add, and in the name field type: Mount Script

In the command field type: /usr/local/bin/mountscript.sh

Click add. Close out everything and reboot!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of ways to do that, but in the end you will have the same sorts of problems you are having. Just save your stuff to a small ntfs partition in the first place.